# Peculiar behavior of CRS Selector dialog in QGIS 3.0

Tags: qgis-3

I installed QGIS 3.0 on my computer and noted that when I accessed the CRS Selector dialog by any method it was very slow, and it seemed to slow my whole system (in any case, during the time I was waiting for the CRS dialog to appear, my mouse wouldn't move or it moved every few seconds in large steps).

Two installations on other computers did not have this issue, and the CRS Selector dialog opened immediately. I completely removed QGIS 3.0 and QGIS 2.18 (using Revo Unistaller), rebooted, and reinstalled QGIS 3.0. I got the same behavior, so it seems to me something on my system not related to QGIS is the culprit but I am at a loss as to what it may be.

Comment: Same, recommend using the LTR version 2.18 and wait till vesrion 3.0 comes out.

Comment: QGIS 3.0 is in early release and has some bugs. Please make a bug report! Issues won't be fixed if no one reports them. https://issues.qgis.org/issues

Comment: There was an early bug (pre-release) that crashed various Linux versions of QGIS, on trying to change the CRS, so possibly this is related.